# Сжатие изображения на клиенте

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob, webp, compression

Моя функция для сжатия на клиенте и преобразования в webp ниже.
Вопрос - почему при сжатии одного и того же изображения весом 2,5мб в десктопном хроме оно сжимается до 15кб, а в любом мобильном браузере (на айфоне во всяком случае) до 250кб ? И как это можно поправить.

```
function arrayBufferToWebP(data, { quality, width, height } = {}) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    image.onload = function (e) {
      if (width && !height) {
        if (width < e.target.width) {
          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = (width / e.target.width) * e.target.height;
        } else {
          canvas.width = e.target.width;
          canvas.height = e.target.height;
        }
      } else if (!width && height) {
        if (height < e.target.height) {
          canvas.width = (height / e.target.height) * e.target.width;
          canvas.height = height;
        } else {
          canvas.width = e.target.width;
          canvas.height = e.target.height;
        }
      } else {
        canvas.width = width || e.target.width;
        canvas.height = height || e.target.height;
      }

      URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.src);
      context.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', quality);
      const base64 = dataURL.split(',')[1];
      const binaryString = atob(base64);
      const length = binaryString.length;
      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(length);

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      resolve({
        uint8Array,
        base64,
      });
    };

    image.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(e);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: никак. раз преобразованием занимается внутренняя часть canvas производительность может меняться в зависимости от браузера